# Cross Compile zlib for ARM

Tags: gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, arm, zlib

I try cross compile zlib for arm-poky-linux-gnueabi but I've an error when I launch make :

```
...:~/zlib-1.2.11$ AR=$HOST-ar CC=$HOST-gcc RANLIB=$HOST-ranlib ./configure --prefix=$HOME/zlibARM 
Checking for shared library support... 
Building shared library libz.so.1.2.11 with arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc. 
Checking for size_t... Yes. 
Checking for off64_t... Yes. 
Checking for fseeko... Yes. 
Checking for strerror... Yes. 
Checking for unistd.h... Yes. 
Checking for stdarg.h... Yes. 
Checking whether to use vs[n]printf() or s[n]printf()... using vs[n]printf(). 
Checking for vsnprintf() in stdio.h... Yes. 
Checking for return value of vsnprintf()... Yes. 
Checking for attribute(visibility) support... Yes.

...:~/zlib-1.2.11$ make
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O3 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DHAVE_HIDDEN -I. -c -o example.o test/example.c
make: execvp: arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc : Trop de niveaux de liens symboliques
Makefile:147: recipe for target 'example.o' failed
make: *** [example.o] Error 127
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: What happens when you execute: `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc --version`?

Answer (score 9):

I know this post is already 7 months old, but I was able to successfully cross-compile zlib for ARM (on MacOS), with the following configure command:

```sh
CHOST=arm \
CC=<PATH_TO_CROSS_GCC> \
AR=<PATH_TO_CROSS_AR> \
RANLIB=<PATH_TO_CROSS_RANLIB> \
./configure \
--prefix=<INSTALL_PATH>
```

Where `PATH_TO_CROSS_GCC`, `PATH_TO_CROSS_AR` and `PATH_TO_CROSS_GCC` point to the cross compilation tools (In my case, I use crosstool-NG).

What eventually made it work for me was specifying the `CHOST=arm`, which caused it to actually use the specified `ar`.

Hopefully this could help someone down the line.

Comment: It would be enough to just specify `CHOST=<target>` and `CC`, `AR`, etc. will be automatically configured with the `<target>-` prefix, JFYI.

Comment: @galaxy I think my cross compilation tooling setup is a bit "odd", as it does not automatically pick up those locations, which is why I had to explicitly define them.

Answer (score 2):

This is also worked for me.

```sh
# CROSS_PREFIX=<path-to-toolchain>- ./configure --prefix=<path-to-install>
# example:
CROSS_PREFIX=arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi- ./configure --prefix=~/rootfs/usr/local
make
make install
```

**Edit:**
I have exported my toolchain path, so I don't need to write full path of my toolchain.